# Cannot import flask into test file

Tags: python, flask

I have running following code for test purpose.

My file name is `app.py`

My code is:

```
from flask import flask
app = flask (_name_)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "Welcome!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When I run this code, it gives the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ravi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\app.py", line 1, in <module>
from flask import flask
ImportError: cannot import name 'flask
```

Any thoughts as to why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

One little fix, The import should be:

```
from flask import Flask
```

Instead of:

```
from flask import flask
```

Also update the line:

```
app = flask (_name_)
```

To:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Comment: i think it works . but i got new error 'flask is not defind'  sorry i am new for python so i just cant help myself in it

Comment: @RaviPardhan , I've added an edit section to my answer.